# How to discover onvif cam in nodejs

Tags: node.js, discovery, onvif

i am trying to use the probe function in nodejs to discover ONVIF cam and it doesn't work.
when i am looking in the wireshark i can't find any broadcast message sending from my computer.
here is the code:

```
var onvif = require('onvif');
onvif.Discovery.on('device', function(cam){
        // function will be called as soon as NVT responses
        logger.info("SensorAutoDiscover find camera: " + cam.hostname);
    });
onvif.Discovery.probe();
```

Comment: Where are you looking for the broadcast message? Did you configure the location of the broadcast message elsewhere?

Comment: i am just using the onvif example for the discovery. just like it's explain in here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/onvif. and the code inside the onvif.Discovery.on('device', function(cam){ is never been called.

Comment: i am not sure where i need to check it. but, i am also using the onvif program and over there i can see this device (when i am opening the wire shark i can see a broadcast message from my computer to 239.255.255.250 in order to find the device)

Comment: Ignore the last (now deleted) comment, it's probably not a probes disabled issue if the function isn't being called? Can I ask how you know it's not being called? Just because the program doesn't output anything, or are you checking somewhere else?

Comment: i have tried to use the debugger and i didn't stop over there. also, nothing is been printed to the logger. and on the wireshark i can't see and UDP message been sent

Comment: Really basic, I know, but have to tried putting a ```console.log("foo");``` inside the function just to double-check? If it outputs then you know for (almost) sure the function is being called, if not it probably isn't...

Comment: didn't worked. any idea?

Comment: Could there be some sort of problem with the onvif code library at all? Is it actually getting required in, do you know?

Comment: i will trying to debug the onvif code. thanks

Comment: It's ok. No problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yesterday I've changed SOAP message for `onvif.Discovery.probe` method because a lot of cameras wont response on old message. Please try new version from github: `npm install https://github.com/agsh/onvif.git` and let me know your results.